# Storing resources for unit and espresso tests

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, android-testing

Currently, I'm storing the same resources in

```
/test/resources/sample.txt //for unit tests
/main/asssets/sample.txt //for espresso tests
```

can I store them in one place?
If yes, how can I read them in my tests?
Preferably, I would like to open them as the File object, not InputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally decided that the best solution, in this case, is to store everything in assets folder (in mock flavor).

You can open them from instrumentation test:

```
activityRule.activity.assets.open("sample.txt")
```

from unit tests:

```
private val ASSET_BASE_PATH = "../app/src/mock/assets/"

fun openAsset(filename: String): InputStream {
    return FileInputStream(ASSET_BASE_PATH + filename)
```